# Compiling a freestanding flat binary causes the ouput binary to be huge

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86, kernel

I am try to build a basic 32 bit kernel:

kernel.c

```
void main() {
    char* video_memory = (char*)0xb8000;
    *video_memory = 'X';
}
```

kernel_entry.asm

```
[bits 32]
[extern main]
call main
jmp $
```

I run the following commands: 
Compiling the kernel.c: `gcc -m32 -fno-pie -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o` 
Assembling the kernel_entry.asm: `nasm kernel_entry.asm -f elf -o kernel_entry.o` 
Linking the objects: `ld -m elf_i386 -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o kernel.o --oformat binary`

When i tested the output binary it works successfully, but after disassembling the binary for examination i found that the binary was 128MB which is huge (it is filled with 0x00) considering the amount of code I have so what have I done wrong

#### Update

This is the ouput from: `objdump -x kernel.bin`
after running (same linking command but not outputting a binary): `ld -m elf_i386 -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o kernel.o`

```
kernel.bin:     file format elf32-i386
kernel.bin
architecture: i386, flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
start address 0x00001000

Program Header:
    LOAD off    0x00000000 vaddr 0x00000000 paddr 0x00000000 align 2**12
         filesz 0x000000b4 memsz 0x000000b4 flags r--
    LOAD off    0x00001000 vaddr 0x00001000 paddr 0x00001000 align 2**12
         filesz 0x0000001d memsz 0x0000001d flags r-x
    LOAD off    0x00002000 vaddr 0x00002000 paddr 0x00002000 align 2**12
         filesz 0x00000038 memsz 0x00000038 flags r--
   STACK off    0x00000000 vaddr 0x00000000 paddr 0x00000000 align 2**4
         filesz 0x00000000 memsz 0x00000000 flags rw-

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         0000001d  00001000  00001000  00001000  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .eh_frame     00000038  00002000  00002000  00002000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .comment      0000001b  00000000  00000000  00002038  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 kernel_entry.asm
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 kernel.c
00000000         *UND*  00000000 _start
00003000 g       .eh_frame  00000000 __bss_start
00001007 g     F .text  00000016 main
00003000 g       .eh_frame  00000000 _edata
00003000 g       .eh_frame  00000000 _end
```

Comment: Note that your definition of `video_memory` is dangerous and may be optimised out.  You need to add a `volatile` qualifier.

Comment: Most likely in your linker script is placing .text segment somewhere 128MB away from your assembly (which probably at address 0). Then it generates this 128MB file.

Comment: Are you asking why code compiled with optimizations disabled is not optimized? Your question is only relevant when compiling with an `-O` option such as `-O3`.

Comment: @0___________ I do not have a linker script

Comment: @Lundin even with `-O3` the binary is still 128MB

Comment: @AhmedFawzy you always have - the default one. Do you think that the elf file is linking magically itself?

Comment: How are you disassembling the binary for examination? The commands you gave seem to work as expected here on my Ubuntu 22.04 (seems from another post you might be using same version) and produce a `kernel.bin` file that is slightly bigger than 4KiB.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Currently I am using "6.2.13-arch1-1" and I did not need to disassemble I just checked the file size, are you sure you are using the same commands and compiling to 32-bit because when i do not compile to 32-bit i get an 8KiB binary (I am quite inexperienced at this topic so feel free to correct me)

Comment: Okay so if you are using 6.2.13-arch1-1 then it is a different version of the tool chain than I have. The 128MiB you talk about would suggest it could be Linux linker script related given the start address for a 32- bit Linux program is 0x8048000 which is just over 128MiB. Anyway, this is a good reason why it is generally recommended to use an ELF cross compiler.

Comment: You don't need to disassemble to see the filesize. But if you want to know what the linker put 128MiB away from the start of the file, you should hexdump or something.  You told it to link the `text` section at `0x1000` for some reason, but if there were any other non-empty sections, they'll still go where the default linker script wants them.  Check your object files for allocatable sections, maybe with `readelf -a`, and check the end of a hexdump of your binary for ASCII text that might give clues.

Comment: I solved this by using an ELF cross compiler like @MichaelPetch said, but I still do not understand why I thought that is was enough to use the "-m32" on the normal gcc, or does this have something to do with the linker script used

Comment: To answer that question assemble/compile link the code the way you were without the cross compiler and instead of the link command you were using, change it to `ld -m elf_i386 -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o kernel.o` (notice it isn't outputting binary anymore). Now use `objdump -x kernel.bin` and add the output to your question. The output info might suggest what the linker did in your case.

Comment: The output of `objdump` doesn't suggest it would be generating a 128MiB file (There is an `.eh_frame` section and then a small `.comment` section). Has the `kernel.bin` file ever been 128MiB in size (like shown with `ls -l kernel.bin`). Is the actual file size about 128 megabytes??

Comment: I can only think of one thing that may be going on and that is there is a bug with using `--oformat binary` . There was a bug in the Windows GCC builds at one time as well. I am curious - without using a cross compiler with the original code that was a problem - if you link it to an ELF file first and then use `objcopy` to convert it to a binary is it correct?

Comment: For example you'd replace this command `ld -m elf_i386 -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o kernel.o --oformat binary` with `ld -m elf_i386 -o kernel.elf -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o kernel.o` and then convert that ELF file to a binary file with `objcopy -O kernel.elf kernel.bin` . Doing it this way is actually preferred.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I tried this but `objcopy` gives me `objcopy: st8fW9vM: invalid bfd target`